# join two rdds to make an adjacency list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to spark, I have two rdds which I want to join to make an adjacency list

```
RDD1 (nodes): (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)

RDD2 (Edges): ((a,b), (a,e), (f, a), (k,l) ...)
```

now I want to join these two rdds to create an adjacency list like this

```
( (a,(b,e,..)), (b,(f,....), (g()) ,...)
#assuming that g is not connected to any node , also filter (k,l) because k and l are not in the nodes rdd
```

and also later on I need to find the count of nodes and edges in total.

Comment: Could clarify this: _need to find the count of nodes and edges in total_? Does it mean that adjacency list is only a temporary structure?

Comment: It means that I need both the count and the adjacency list.

Comment: OK, have you tried anything? While there is no efficient solution in PySpark this is just a single call to a built in method.

Comment: Yeah I have made some progress. I have now one rdd with (a ,(a,e),(a,b)..)
now I want to change that to (a,(e,b,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I am understanding correctly you wish to have an adjacency list where the final RDD consists of key-values pairs with the key being the node and the value a list of it's edges. Perhaps something as shown below is what you had in mind? Though I believe if you want 'g' to be shown in your final RDD it would make sense to have it in your edges list as ('g', '') since you wish to convey that it has no edges.

To join we need to convert the nodes list to a pair RDD, so first we parallelize to create the RDD and then map a dummy value so that we have key-value pairs.

Now we can join the two RDDs to each other and the result will be only the keys that exist in both RDDs in this case 'a' and 'f'. Finally we strip the dummy value we added to the the nodes RDD and groupByKey to group our values together.

```
nodes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
edges = [('a','b'), ('a','e'), ('f', 'a'), ('k','l')]
nodesRDD = sc.parallelize(nodes).map(lambda n: (n, ''))
edgesRDD = sc.parallelize(edges)
joinedRDD = nodesRDD.join(edgesRDD).map(lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[1][1]))
groupedRDD = joinedRDD.groupByKey()

groupedRDD.map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()
```

Out[146]: [('f', ['a']), ('a', ['b', 'e'])]

Count is similar but now we do not care about the actually node values, only their counts:

```
nodes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
edges = [('a','b'), ('a','e'), ('f', 'a'), ('k','l')]
nodesRDD = sc.parallelize(nodes).map(lambda n: (n, 0))
edgesRDD = sc.parallelize(edges).map(lambda tup: (tup[0], 1))
joinedRDD = nodesRDD.join(edgesRDD).map(lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[1][1]))
reducedRDD = joinedRDD.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

reducedRDD.collect()
```

Out[159]: [('f', 1), ('a', 2)]

Comment: Don't use `reduceByKey` to concatenate lists. It is never better than `groupByKey` and on JVM significantly worse.

Comment: It is kind of funny that I had characters only as example, they are strings in the actual problem, now I get something like this
((string1,[s,t,r,i,n,g,2,...])....)

Comment: @zero323 good point, I have edited the transforms for groupByKey to prevent unnecessary garbage collection.

Comment: @AzeemAkhter interesting I just ran a test with all values as strings and I still get the correct result, perhaps try the version I just edited that now uses groupByKey?

Comment: Yeah it works fine now , however in the final adjacency list instead of only the nodes one key is connected to, i have tuples with '' and the other node.
how can I make it so that it contains the nodes name only? I suspect a map here but how to map on multiple values of one key